# JetPack Compose Lambda understanding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-function-type

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWHUr.png)i am new to jetpack Compose. I have opened my first jetpack compose project today. I am little confuse regarding the initial syntax. i have highlighted the curly brackets. My question is are the lambdas inside lambdas? i have went through kotlin tutorial and haven't found any such structure. A little explanation  with some example will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

I am just trying to understand the mentioned code structure

Answer (score 0):

> are the lambdas inside lambdas?

Yes, these are nested lambdas. Before you get your answer you should familiar with higher-order function that is the functions which takes another function as paramenter or as return type are called higher-order functions.

[A higher-order function is a function that takes functions as parameters, or returns a function.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions)

*If trailing parameter (last one) of higher-order function is itself a function then you can pass the function in the form of lambda.*

**For example:**
Here is the listener for the motion done on any view.

```
fun attachMotionListener(
    onDragged: () -> Unit,
    onClicked: () -> Unit
)
```

Now you can call the function in two ways:

```
// Here we have passed the paramenters without using any special syntax
attachMotionListener(
    onDragged = { /* do something when dragged */ }
    onClicked = { /* do something when clicked */ }
)

// Here we use the trailing lambda syntax
attachMotionListener(
    onDragged = { /* do something when dragged */ }
) {
    /* do something when clicked */
}
```

By using this technique the composable functions are defined as the last parameter of `setContent` is of function type that's why we use *trailing-lambda* using *curly-brackets*. As you can see in the following code of `button` from `material-3 docs`:

```
@Composable
fun Button(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = ButtonDefaults.shape,
    colors: ButtonColors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
    elevation: ButtonElevation? = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = ButtonDefaults.ContentPadding,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
)
```

Here you can see that the `onClick` is not trailing so we can't use *trailing-lambda syntax* here but the trailing parameter is also of type function here we can use the syntax and you also might have noticed it:

```
Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
    Text("Hello World!")
}
```

You might have noticed `@Composable` annotation its telling the compiler that this is composable function and any `Composable` component can be called in the another function that's why the `content` parameter in `Button` has also this annotation used and hence we can call other composable within the scope of this function.

Comment: Thanks Atul Sharma for your detail answer with examples. It was very helpful :)

Comment: Yeah i tried to upvote but my account is new and it want my reputation to be 15 at least

Answer (score 0):

Each basic composables like Surface and Theme are just functions(not objects) that takes another composabe lambda as the last argument.

Check the code below for definition of surface

```
@Composable
@NonRestartableComposable
fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(color),
    tonalElevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    shadowElevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
```

[If the last argument after default parameters is a lambda, you can pass it either as a named argument or outside the parentheses](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments) .  So they are just nested lambdas used as last arguments.